# Recursive to Tail-recursive in scala

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I have the following code

```
object TailRec
{
    def func1(n:Int) : Int =
    {
        if (n < 10)
            func2(n)
        else
            func1(n/10) + func2(n % 10)
    }

    def func2(n: Int) : Int =
    {
        @tailrec def _func2(n: Int, result: Int): Int =
        {
            if (n <= 1)
                result
            else
                _func2(n-1,n*result)
        }
        _func2(n,1)
    }

    def test(n: Int) : Boolean =
    {
        if (n > 2)
            n == func1(n)
        else
            false
    }

}
```

I managed to rewrite func2 but I am not quite sure how to convert the bool function. I thought about match and case but I still need to call func1 to get the result for comparison. The other problem is how to break up the double function call in func1 itself. Any hints?

Comment: The only function with `Boolean` return type is `test`. It is not recursive. Could you please clarify what exactly you want to rewrite?

Comment: The task was to make the algorithm tail-recursive. I already rewrote func2 but I am stuck on how to rewrite the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already converted `func2` into tail-recursive form.
Similarly, using an additional accumulator, you can convert `func1` into a tail-recursive form (I have modified the interface of `func1`, but you could also create another inner helper function). Since `test` isn't recursive, nothing has to be done here.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object TailRec {
  @tailrec def func1(n:Int, acc: Int): Int = {
    if (n < 10) func2(n)
    else func1(n / 10, acc + func2(n % 10))
  }

  def func2(n: Int): Int = {
    @tailrec def _func2(n: Int, result: Int): Int = {
      if (n <= 1) result
      else _func2(n-1,n*result)
    }
    _func2(n,1)
  }

  def test(n: Int): Boolean = (n > 2) && (n == func1(n, 0))
}
```

Comment: The boolean caused me such a headache but of course it is already final. Thank you very much good Sir - you made my day :)